# How to save 1st table's id in 2nd table's id in HttpPost method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables now I want to save `Center_ID` in patient tables's `CentreId` while adding patient data in `HttpPost` method of ASP.NET MVC. How can I fetch it automatically and save it?

Here is a code.

I have mention session id of `centerid` in patient table. Now I want to save it in patient table column, but it is null. Please mention the right way of doing this.

```
public ActionResult patientRegistration(AllViewModel patient)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {

            int Id = (int)Session["ID"];

            var data = new PatientRegistration
            {
                CentreId = Id,
                Patient_Name = patient.Prefix + " " + patient.Patient_Name,
                Patient_DOB = patient.Patient_DOB,
                Gender = patient.Gender,
                TwoDDiagnostic_name = patient.TwoDDiagnostic_name,
                TwoDDiagnostic_price = patient.TwoDDiagnostic_price,
                ThreeDDiagnostic_name= patient.ThreeDDiagnostic_name,
                ThreeDDiagnostic_price = patient.ThreeDDiagnostic_price,
                RefferalDoctor = patient.RefferalDoctor,
                Patient_Reports = patient.Patient_Reports,
                Patient_MobileNo = patient.Patient_MobileNo,
                Patient_Email = patient.Patient_Email,
                Patient_TelephoneNo = patient.Patient_TelephoneNo,
                Patient_State = patient.Patient_State,
                Patient_City = patient.Patient_City,
                Patient_Address = patient.Patient_Address,
                Patient_Area = patient.Patient_Area,
                Patient_PaymentMode = patient.Patient_PaymentMode,
                Patient_PaymentAmount = patient.Patient_PaymentAmount,
                Patient_Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
                BankName = patient.BankName,
                chequedate=patient.chequedate,
                ChequeNo = patient.ChequeNo,
            };
            db.PatientRegistrations.Add(data);
            db.SaveChanges();
            State_Bind();
            City_Bind();

            return RedirectToAction("PatientDetails");
            //ViewData["CentreCode"] = Session["CenterCode"];
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }

    }
    try
    {

    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        Exception raise = dbEx;
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                    validationError.ErrorMessage);
                // raise a new exception nesting  
                // the current instance as InnerException  
                raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
            }
        }
        throw raise;
    }
    State_Bind();
    return View(patient);

}
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 [Center_ID]
      ,[CenterCode]
      ,[NameofCenter]
      ,[CenterIncharge]
      ,[Center_MobileNo]
      ,[Center_TelephoneNo]
      ,[Center_Email]
      ,[Center_Passwrd]
      ,[Center_Address]
      ,[Center_Area]
      ,[Center_PinCode]
      ,[Center_State]
      ,[Center_City]
      ,[Center_Status]
      ,[Center_Active]
      ,[Center_Date]
  FROM [TrueScan].[dbo].[AddCenter]

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 [Patient_ID]
      ,[Patient_Name]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[Patient_DOB]
      ,[CentreId]
      ,[Patient_CenterCode]
      ,[Payment_Status]
      ,[AgePatient]
      ,[Doctor_ID]
  FROM [TrueScan].[dbo].[PatientRegistration]

Comment: Can you share the **code** you are using (in the question, not in the comment section!) and clarify your question? If you have the IDs you want to insert at hand, where is the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase i had attached code's images..

Comment: Please add the code to the question, not any images of your code

Comment: @NicoHaase please see the code